# Axios/Nuxt "Certificate has expired" only when directly opening page, but not for a link from another page

Tags: javascript, twitter, axios, certificate, nuxt.js

I have a website I am helping to maintain (but did not build myself), using Nuxt.js and Axios. It is currently showing an odd server behavior on the Home page. If I directly visit the home page (say: `https://example.org`):

- Browser: Server error (500)
- Server: Certificate has expired (for the twitter feed data call)

This error also happens when I am on `example.org/about` (which works) and hit a link formed like: `<a href="/" class="navbar-item logo-text">Home</a>`

However, if I visit the home page (both show link as `https://example.org`) via a link on say `example.org/about` which is formed like: `<a href="/" class="navbar-item nuxt-link-active"><span>Home</span></a>`:

- Browser: Page works!
- Server: No errors

So, oddly enough, even for two different links for '/' one leads to the error but the other does not (and they both display the same thing in the URL bar). If I open the link directly at `example.org:5000/tweets` then it works fine (footnote: not sure why the design choice was made to use a different port there, possibly related). Has anyone seen this kind of behavior and know why that might happen? It persists on safe mode and on all major browsers. No changes were made with the code from when it worked to when it stopped working in the last couple of days. The specific error that I receive is shown like the below.

```
{ Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)
  code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED',
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.16.2' },
     baseURL: 'https://example.org:5000/',
     method: 'get',
     url: 'https://example.org:5000/tweets',
     data: undefined },
  request:
   Writable {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options:
      { protocol: 'https:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        hostname: 'example.org',
        port: '5000',
        path: '/tweets',
        method: 'get',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/tweets' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 0,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'GET /tweets HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.16.2\r\nHost: example.org:5000\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/tweets',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'https://example.org:5000/tweets' },
  response: undefined,
  statusCode: 500,
  name: 'NuxtServerError' }
```

Comment: Do you use SSR or SSG? Did you tried hosting it somewhere and see if you can replicate the issue on a platform like Netlify or Heroku? This is probably a SSL certificate configuration issue.

Comment: This site has Nuxt.js in there, which I believe is SSR (never built a project with it myself). I was initially wondering if this was an issue with LetsEncrypt (which had its own certificate expire recently).

Comment: Without more code, I will not be able to answer tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of Node resolved this issue for me. I was experiencing an identical issue to what you described on Node v8.10.0. I upgraded to Node v14.18.1 and restarted Nuxt, and now the site works normally.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Success. This does appear to be the issue for this particular problem. It was a bit trickier for me, as some dependencies needed to be updated (bcrypt) and I ended up going with nvm to get the job done, but it worked out in the end.